Unable to parse Build/Test.framework.js.br
I am trying to host my Unity WebGL Build on Firebase Hosting and I am using the Brotli compression for better performance and smaller build size. I saw in a post that Firebase supports brotli by default but still it throws this error:

Unable to parse Build/Test.framework.js.br! This can happen if
build compression was enabled but web server hosting the content was
misconfigured to not serve the file with HTTP Response Header
"Content-Encoding: br" present. Check browser Console and Devtools
Network tab to debug.


I have tried configuring firebase.json for brotli (by asking ChatGPT) but it didn't help. Corrently yhis is how my firebase.json looks:
{
  "hosting": {
    "site": "test",
    "public": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/Build/*.unityweb",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Encoding",
            "value": "br"
          },
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/vnd.unity"
          },
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/Build/*.br",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Encoding",
            "value": "br"
          },
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/vnd.unity"
          },
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

and my publishing build settings looks something like this:

I do know that enabling the decompression fallback resolves the issue but it does not use brotli which is not what I want.

According to this firebase already does server side compression in which case disabling it in the Unity build would indeed be the best solution Disables compression. Use this option if you want to implement your own compression in post-processing  scripts . You should also use it if you plan to use static compression on the hosting server.

If I disable that option then I receive this message in the console when the WebGL build is loading: You can reduce startup time if you configure your web server to add "Content-Encoding: br" response header when serving "Build/Test.framework.js.unityweb" file.

yeah .. possible that Unity build thinks that .. but if Firebase indeed does server side compression anyway then it shouldn't matter
